# Run Python chat client script in windows

Tags: python, linux, sockets, python-sockets

i made a chat server and chat client python script the server runs on a port and as many as i like clients can connect and chat like an irc chatroom, works fine on linux, but not running on windows

here is the chat client code

```
import sys
import socket
import select

def chat_client():
    if(len(sys.argv) < 3) :
        print 'Usage : python chat_client.py hostname port'
        sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    # connect to remote host
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print 'Unable to connect'
        sys.exit()

    print 'Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages'
    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()

    while 1:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

        # Get the list sockets which are readable
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

        for sock in ready_to_read:             
            if sock == s:
                # incoming message from remote server, s
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if not data :
                    print '\nDisconnected from chat server'
                    sys.exit()
                else :
                    #print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()     

            else :
                # user entered a message
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()
                s.send(msg)
                sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush() 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(chat_client())
```

the problem lies in that windows does not view sockets like files as linux do so the select function not working (I think)

problem starts from this line

```
ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(socket_list , [], [])
```

can i port this script to windows ?

Comment: The sockets are not the problem. In Python, you can use Windows sockets with select. But you cannot use Windows' `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` with select. See the [first paragraph in the documentation of the select module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html).

Comment: can you suggest an workaround ?